# Adding a New Webpage to an App with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am struggling to add a second module to a web app I am running locally. Currently, the app opens to the 'home' page module which displays the web map. However, I am attempting to create a 'landing' page module that is opened first (then when the appropriate button is selected the 'home' page module loads). However, I seem to be getting lost in the framework.

I have created a second html document with ng-app="LandingPage" in the body. As well as a simple landing.controller.js

```
angular.module('ap.components.landing.controller', [])
    .controller('LandingCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

and landing.app.js for the module

```
angular.module('ap.components', [
    'ap.components.landing'
]);

angular.module('ap.components.landing', [
    'ap.components.landing.controller'
]);

angular.module('LandingPage', ['ui.router', 'ap.routes', 'ap.components.landing'])
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
            var $state = $injector.get("$state");
            $state.go('landing');
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

And I added a new state to my routes.js file

```
angular.module('ap.routes', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('landing', {
                url: '/landing',
                templateUrl: 'src/components/landing/landing.html',
                controller: 'LandingCtrl',
            });
```

I attempted to add information server-side as well in my express.js but that seems to be incorrect/unable to differentiate between the angularApp and landingApp

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '500mb', extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '500mb', extended: true}));
    app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));
    app.set('angularApp', 'client/src');
    // app.set('landingApp', 'client/src');
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(app.get('angularApp') + '/index.html');
    });
    // app.get('/landing', function (req, res) {
    //   res.sendFile(app.get('landingApp') + '/index.html');
    // });
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
```

I receive this [image: error] when I run the code. Each of these are just error codes that don't seem to help me. Am I missing a document that needs to be added for the new module or is it more likely I missed a link in one of my existing documents? I wasn't able to find good example documentation of how to nest modules so if anyone has that it would also be appreciated.

Comment: instead of `app.get('/', ...` try `app.all('/*', ...`.  in your express router.  This is discussed in the FAQ for ui-router:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: That didn't do it but thank you for opening a new track for me to look at